# Why :first-child select all children?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select only the very first links from "dropdown menu" (the ones with "ONE" text), but `:first-child` selects them all.

Link:

http://jsfiddle.net/773Xd/1/

Sorry for the mess in the HTML part, but I'm customizing Wordpress theme and it produces so many classes and ids.

The most important thing is at the end of CSS file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change your CSS selector to this...

```
#page-navigation ul li .sub-menu li:first-child a
```

(i.e. put pseudo class `:first-child` on the `li`, not the `a`).

[See it on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/773Xd/4/)

The old selector didn't work because `a` is always the first child of the `li` elements.

But in the new selector, the `li` is the first child of the `ul` elements.

Comment: Well, there was the same post from another user above. Why deleted? O.o

Comment: @omicz Probably because it came after mine and basically said the same thing. It was correct, though.